# Should I pass DbContext to enttity constructor?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following entity class that generates a match code so I can ensure that duplicate matches are not entered.

```
public class CompanyMatch
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// {CompanyID}-{CompanyMatchMethod}-{CompaniesHouseRecordID}
    /// </summary>
    [StringLength(100)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    [Required]
    public string MatchCode { get; set; }
    public CompanyMatchMethod CompanyMatchMethod { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual CompaniesHouseRecord CompaniesHouseRecord { get; set; }

    public CompanyMatch(int companyId, CompanyMatchMethod matchMethod, int companiesHouseId)
    {
        this.MatchCode = companyId.ToString() + "-" + matchMethod + "-" + companiesHouseId.ToString();
        this.CompanyMatchMethod = matchMethod;
        using (var db = new PlaceDBContext())
        {
            this.Company = db.Companies.Find(companyId);
            this.CompaniesHouseRecord = db.CompaniesHouseRecords.Find(companiesHouseId);
        }
    }
}
```

I thought it would be easier to have the constructor handle the creating of the code so I made the constructor also populate the relationship.

The problem with this is that the calling code that created the `MatchMethod` then needs to attach the nested `Company` and `CompaniesHouseRecord` before it can add the new `MatchMethod`.

This all feels clumsy and I am wondering if the constructor should maybe take the `DbContext` as a parameter or I should do this a different way?

I am doing it like this and it works fine but I am not sure if this is a bad way of doing it:

```
public class CompanyMatch
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// {CompanyID}-{CompanyMatchMethod}-{CompaniesHouseRecordID}
    /// </summary>
    [StringLength(100)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    [Required]
    public string MatchCode { get; set; }
    public CompanyMatchMethod CompanyMatchMethod { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual CompaniesHouseRecord CompaniesHouseRecord { get; set; }

    public CompanyMatch(int companyId, CompanyMatchMethod matchMethod, int companiesHouseId, DbContext db)
    {
        this.MatchCode = companyId.ToString() + "-" + matchMethod + "-" + companiesHouseId.ToString();
        this.CompanyMatchMethod = matchMethod;
        this.Company = db.Companies.Find(companyId);
        this.CompaniesHouseRecord = db.CompaniesHouseRecords.Find(companiesHouseId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use (wheter you're going with entity framework or edmx) some [navigation properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx)?

They will automatically fetch the relations for you.

Comment: How would I use navigation property to achieve this?